# Angular startup time: when I develop my angular 6 application in watch mode, it takes long time to load

Tags: angular, app-startup

Angular startup time: when I develop my angular 6 application in watch mode, it takes long time to load. I can’t afford the longer load time on every save. How can I cut down this time so I can be more productive?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are using [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve). If so, you could disable rebuilding:

```
ng serve --watch=false
```

If rebuilding is fine, disable live-reload with `--liveReload=false`.